# SSMS run as

Tags: sql-server

I am responsible for managing a few domains SS instances across our enterprise.  New rule is to have domain specific logins with rights associated for each.  No big deal there.

I wanted to put some folders on my desktop for each domain that would have the "run as" pre set.

SSMS or SSBPA each come back with an error telling me that the directory doesn't exist pointing to my \SqlWb.exe or  either flavor.

Can this not be saved off into a folder on the desktop?  Or is that a security issue leving the creds?

TIA

__Stephen

Comment: Are you saving the folders on your desktop, or the run-as credential desktop?  Does the run-as credential have access to your desktop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me that the run-as credential doesn't have access to your current desktop.  You may have better luck putting the folders in a neutral location on your C: drive where the run-as credential and your credential has access to it.

JFV

Comment: That change of folders home was the trick to stop the error.

You do not save the Run As data unfortunately.  So I have to set that properly for each data center still.  :(